# Monte Carlo simulation of PI, in Python

Tags: python

I know there are countless ways to do this that are better than my way, but I really want to figure out what I'm doing wrong here.
I'm trying to get to the value of PI doing a monte carlo simulation,but I don't get what I'm doing wrong

## PI Monte Carlo

```
import random
import pylab


def MonteCarloPI(numtries):
    circle = 0
    for i in range (numtries):
        a = (float(random.random())+1)**0.5
        b = float(random.random())*a
        if b <= 1:
            circle += 1
        rapportoAree = (circle/numtries)
    return rapportoAree*4

print(MonteCarloPI(1000))
```

*Edit*

The point of this is to find the area of the circle without using x and y coordinates.
The idea is that if 'a' is a random number between 1 and sqrt2 and then 'b' is a random number between 0 and 'a' In theory all values of 'b' that are <1 should be inside the circle, so I should have the number of points in the circle and the number of total points, that way I can calculate the fraction that is proportional to PI

[I hope this image can explain better than my words](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySbH7.jpg)

Comment: Well, what's wrong with it that you want help with? Are you getting an exception? Unexpected wildly wrong values? Values that don't converge as fast as you read that the algorithm ought to?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to find Euclidean norm (sqrt(random.random()**2 + random.random()**2)? I don't understand how you calculate a and b.

Comment: @abarnert I'm getting 3.4 as the mean, so it's wrong

Comment: The calculations of `a` and `b` seem entirely wrong -- why are you taking the square root of a random number plus one?

Comment: @user2285236  a is a random number between 1 and sqrt2, b is a random number between 0 and b
The point is finding the area of the circle without using x and y coordinates

Comment: @EdoardoBusetti you need to adjust your a and b. I don't really understand the idea behind what youre doing with them, but its not checking if they are within the circle.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: The idea is that if 'a' is a random number between 1 and sqrt2 and then 'b' is a random number between 0 and 'a' 
In theory all values of 'b' that are <1 should be inside the circle, so I should have the number of points in the circle and the number of total points, that way I can calculate the fraction that is proportional to PI

Comment: Please edit clarifications into your question.

Comment: @EdoardoBusetti you need to set `a = random.uniform(1.0, 2**0.5)` instead of what you have it to. its not giving a random number in the correct range and then `b = random.uniform(0, a)` should work. Although im not going to try and prove your theory either, so that may or may not work.

Comment: What do you mean in theory? Is it your theory or are you referring to something we don't know?

Comment: @user2285236 My theory, sorry I'm not the best with english

Comment: I think I understood your logic and it is indeed interesting. First issue: `a = (float(random.random())+1)**0.5` doesn't generate uniform numbers. It has a bias towards larger numbers. But even if you use `random.uniform(1, 2**0.5)` the issue doesn't resolve. As I understand you select a point on the edges of the square and then select another random number that's on the line that connects the center and the point you've previously chosen. The issue is here the conditional probability. That may be causing problems with uniformity again.

Comment: @GrantWilliams I tried, it's giving me the same result

Comment: Can you ask this on https://stats.stackexchange.com/ or https://math.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @user2285236
Yeah, you got what I'm trying to do, I think it should work, and I don't get what I'm doing wrong.
I just posted it in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/350129/monte-carlo-simulation-of-pi-in-python

Comment: The problem with the theory as I see it is that uniformly distributed a's don't arise from uniformly distributed angles.

Comment: @EricMittman I'm not entirely sure of what you mean, do you think there is any way to fix this or is the base logic flawed?

Comment: The logic is flawed.

Comment: This is not a homework completion service. Your instructor gave you the assignment, and you need first to do some effort by yourself. If you can't even get started, ask your teacher for help. Isolate your questions into specific programming snippets, and then search the for answers. In case you need a course or tutorial, Stack Overflow is not the right place to ask it. We wish you good luck in your study. See: [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: @sɐunıɔןɐqɐp I have not received any assignment, this is my personal project, I wanted to try an alternative way of doing the monte carlo PI proof.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your distribution of `(a, b)`values is not equivalent to the uniform distribution of `(x, y)` values (Cartesian coordinates).  Your implementation uses something akin to polar coordinates, with a uniform distribution of the radius (over the range of a square) and a quadratically skewed distribution of the reference angle.

As a result, you generate more points within the circle than is proper for the measurement you want.  To fix this, you'll need to alter your formulas to account for the polar transformations you've introduced.

**-- a --**

Your posted formula:

```
a = (float(random.random())+1)**0.5
```

Does *not* yield a uniform distribution over the range (1.0, sqrt(2.0)).  It's more dense the higher you go.  For comparison, let's extend this to the range (1, 10) -- we'll choose a random integer 0-99.

```
a = (random.randint(0, 99) + 1)**0.5
```

All 100 integers are equally likely, but let's look at the resulting distribution.  At the bottom, the results in the range [1.0, 2.0) will be hit with only integers 1 and 2.  At the top, results in the range [9.0, 10.0) -- the same size -- will be hit with integers 80 through 99 (a total of 20 values).  Thus, 9 <= a < 10 is ten times as likely as 1 <= a < 2.

Your formula suffers from a lesser version of this problem.  You can correct this by generating numbers in a uniform distribution over [1.0, sqrt(2.0)].

**-- b --**

To illustrate the problem with `b`, draw some equally-spaced (according to the `a` values you generate) line segments.  What is the total length of these segments?  The "inside" component of each segment is `1.0`, but note that the points represented are *much* more dense near the origin -- inside the circle -- than outside.

To calculate `b`, you need to *undo* the center bias of your polar coordinates.  I will leave this derivation as an exercise for the student ... should you want to continue this line of attack.

Comment: The fix for 'a' still leaves a different problem, namely that the central angle is not a linear transformation of 'a', and is not uniformly distributed.

Comment: You raised the issue that the 'a' is not uniformly distributed. Fixing this is not sufficient to making the scheme work.

Answer (score -1):

Three different methods using Cartesian coordinates.

```
import random
import math

def MonteCarloPI(numtries):
    inside = 0

    for i in range (numtries):

        x2 = random.random()**2
        y2 = random.random()**2

        if (math.sqrt(x2 + y2) < 1.0):
            inside += 1

    return (float(inside) / numtries) * 4
```

outputs:

```
>>> print(MonteCarloPI(1000))
3.14
```

and

```
>>> print(MonteCarloPI(100000))
3.14476
```

you can even clean up the function using the built in math.hypot which calculates euclidean norms:

```
import random

from math import hypot

def MonteCarloPI(numtries):
    inside = 0

    for i in range (numtries):

        if hypot(random.random(), random.random()) < 1:
            inside += 1

    return (float(inside) / numtries) * 4

>>> print(MonteCarloPI(100000))
3.14364
```

or numpy one liner

```
import numpy as np

def MonteCarloPI(n):
    return np.sum(np.random.rand(n)**2+np.random.rand(n)**2<1)/float(n)*4
```

outputs:

```
>>> print(MonteCarloPI(100000))
3.1462
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is not how I want to do it

Comment: @EdoardoBusetti what do you mean by that? Are you not trying to do a simple monte carlo approximation? The only thing i changed for your code is the way a/b are calculated (and circle renamed to inside for clarity).

Comment: Willams
I'm trying to get my calculations of a and b right, not trying to just do the simulation

Comment: @EdoardoBusetti well how are you trying to calculate a and b? because what you are currently doing is completely wrong. you can let us know what approach you are trying to take and edit your original question then we can help with that.

Comment: I added a picture, that should explain better what I'm trying to do